# Left value of an integer

Tags: vb.net

I have a value in variable, say it is `dim a as integer = 145.98`
I tried to take the `Left(a,2)`
but it returned an error instead of returning 14
I also tried `left(a.Tostring,2)`
but error is the same.
Please help me solve it.

Thanks
Furqan

Comment: 145.98 is a double not an integer

Answer (score 7):

First off, you say that you’re using an integer but the number is actually a floating-point number, *not* an integer.

Secondly, the action “take the left of a number” isn’t a meaningful operation. `Left` is a *substring* operation, it’s only defined on strings.

You *can* turn the number into a string and then extract a substring of the decimal representation. This should work. What’s the error?

Finally, some general advice:

Put `Option Strict On` at the very top of ever vb file, or better yet, make this option the default in your settings. Otherwise, you’ve got a veritable hullaballoo waiting to happen because VB is very … “lenient” when it comes to questionable or downright incorrect code. This option fixes this and will flag a lot more errors. For example, the compiler would (rightfully) have complained about your assignment,

```
Dim a As Integer = 145.98
```

because as I said, you’re trying to assign a floating-point number to an integer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, 145.98 is not an integer.  145 is an integer.  You might want to try Double.  Second, you can only take the `left` of a string.  You were on the right track when you added ToString, but you forgot the ()s at the end.

```
Dim a as Integer = 145
Dim b as Double = 145.98
```

Then you can do this:

```
Left(a.ToString(), 2)
Left(b.ToString(), 2)
```

Comment: The `()` symbols are not required in VB.NET.

Comment: Meh, nobody ever got fired for using them.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Left(a.ToString(), 2)` instead.

Comment: Error: Public property Left() as integer has no parameter and its return type can not be indexed.............

Answer (score 0):

If your "integer" is a string, try this:

```
 Dim a As String = "145.98"
 Dim b As Int32 = 0
 Int32.TryParse(a.Substring(0, 2), b)
```

Answer (score 0):

As Konrad has said with option strict this would not compile.  If you don't have it on it will perform a conversion and store only the integer part. At this point you can call `tostring` and then performe any operation on it as a string you would like.

With option strict

Option Strict On

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim I As Integer = CType(142.3, Integer)
        Dim s As String = I.ToString
        Console.WriteLine(Left(s, 2))
    End Sub

End Module
```

With out optiion strict

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim I As Integer = 142.3
        Dim s As String = I
        Console.WriteLine(Left(s, 2))
    End Sub

End Module
```

As you can see from the two example option strict will attempt to perform many conversions for you but does so at the risk of unexpected results.